# Erro ao passar o script de uma tabela do banco Firebird para PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, arquivo, firebird

Estou tentando passar um script de criação e inserção de dados de um banco Firebird para PostgreSQL, porém em algumas tabelas está ocorrendo erro de sintaxe, estou utilizando a ferramenta SQL Manager Interbase & Firebird para gerar os arquivos *.sql das minhas tabelas do banco Firebird. Já tentei via CMD enviar os arquivos para o banco atrav´s do seguinte comando:

**psql -h host -p 5432 -U postgres -d database -f (Local do arquivo *.sql)**

mas o seguinte erro me retorna:

`psql:C:/Backup/Script/CONTROLEIMPRESSOES.sql:573: ERROR: column "DATA" is of type date but expression is of type integer
LINHA 6: (163, 6, 2007-02-01, 29138, 31432, 2294, 160.58, 31388, 33...)`

`DICA: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então fui fazer através do pgAdmin e o único modo de inserir assim no banco foi colocando a data entre `"2007-02-01"`.

Minha dúvida é, como posso gerar um arquivo *.sql onde as datas já venham entre parênteses, para que não precise alterar linha por linha adicionando `""` em cada data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tem a mesma estrutura nos dois bancos e está migrando de um para o outro, pode estar utilizando a ferramenta [FullCopyConvert](http://www.fullcopyconvert.com.br/) que é paga mas acho que a versão de testes pode te ajudar.

Se for um processo a ser executado poucas vezes você pode utilizar um editor de texto com suporte a expressão regular e adicionar aspas nas datas, assim não precisaria fazer manualmente em cada linha. Pode utilizar o [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) e usar a opção de substituir como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Regex Notepad++]

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do Notepad++, se encaixou perfeitamente para o que eu precisava