# Sobre manipulação de String

Tags: string, script

Tenho um problema um tanto curioso, talvez um desafio.

Preciso adicionar ao meu banco de dados a lista de todas as cidades do Brasil, encontrei um SQL com todas do jeito que eu preciso, entretanto, o nome da tabela do SQL se encontra com "aspas" como no exemplo a seguir:

```
INSERT INTO `tb_cidades` VALUES (0001, 01, 'AC', 'Acrelandia');
INSERT INTO `tb_cidades` VALUES (0002, 01, 'AC', 'Assis Brasil');
INSERT INTO `tb_cidades` VALUES (0003, 01, 'AC', 'Brasileia');
INSERT INTO `tb_cidades` VALUES (0004, 01, 'AC', 'Bujari');
INSERT INTO `tb_cidades` VALUES (0005, 01, 'AC', 'Capixaba');
```

Gostaria de saber, como eu faço para criar um script ou algoritmo simples, para trocar o nome 'tb_cidades' para cidades. Tenho a lista com todas, apenas em um arquivo .txt

Comment: Um replace/substituir não resolve o problema?

Comment: Estás usando Linux?

Comment: [Aqui](http://samus.com.br/web/site/artigo-todas_as_cidades_do_brasil_atualizado_e_com_acentos) tem um sql com todas as cidades do brasil

Comment: Como eu disse, rray estou com a lista em .txt, não sei manipular lá;

Comment: Giuliana Bezerra, sim

Comment: Todo editor de texto tem a função de busca/substituição não precisa de script.

Comment: É verdade, o Gedit por exemplo tem find/replace, você poderia usá-lo. O padrão para replace seria: `tb_cidades` -> cidades.

Comment: Usa um editor qualquer de texto.

Comment: Não sabia dessas funções dos editores de texto, consegui resolver meu problema graças a vocês. Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema recentemente, gerei um script com as informações inseridas em meu banco de Dados antigo Firebird para adicionar no PostgreSQL, porém as informações das datas vieram sem as as aspas, a solução que me sugeriram e deu certo foi utilizar o notepad++ e deu funcionou perfeitamente para mim acredito que funcione para você também:

[Link para minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170218/erro-ao-passar-o-script-de-uma-tabela-do-banco-firebird-para-postgresql)