# Capturar ano que esteja fora da regex

Tags: xml, regex, sublime-text

Estou trabalhando com um arquivo de texto usando o `sublime` quero substituir algumas strings onde:
Tenho várias strings parecidas como essa:

```
EMISSAO="2016-04-18 00:00:00"
```

Preciso de uma `regex` que capture onde o ano é inválido, ex: 
Em alguns registros está assim:

```
EMISSAO="65321-04-18 00:00:00"
```

Ou seja, o número 65321 representa o ano e é um ano que sequer existe (inválido), preciso ver onde os anos estão acima de 2017 para corrigir.

Comment: O que você considera como um ano "válido"?

Comment: De 2017 pra baixo.

Comment: Mas 6532 é uma ano válido

Comment: Corrigido na pergunta.

Comment: mas que linguagem ta usando? so na regex fica dificil...

Comment: o problema entao é que alguns anos estao com caracterres a mais? Tipo `65321`, seria para identificar só isso ou saber se o ano é de 2017 pra baixo?

Comment: O que seria `65321`?

Comment: Corrigido a pergunta novamente.

Comment: Em que linguagem? Para especificar a regex..

Comment: É um arquivo texto e estou tentando pegar pelo find do `sublime`

Comment: Especifica isso na pergunta, fica melhor.

Comment: de 1945 - 2017:   /^(194[5-9]|19[5-9]\d|200\d|201[0-7])$/

Comment: Acredito que isso possa te ajudar: ]http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170218/erro-ao-passar-o-script-de-uma-tabela-do-banco-firebird-para-postgresql

Answer (score 5):

Como é algo pontual para se buscar no sublime acredito que o problema seja somente encontrar a parte do ano válido ou inválido , com isso a parte após o ano seria a data que pelo que falou virão corretas.

Com isso para verificar só o ano válido pode usar essa regex:

```
^EMISSAO="(19\d{2})|20(0[0-9]|1[0-7])-/d{2}-\d{2}\s(\d{2}:){2}\d{2})"$
```

Explicando:

**(19\d{2})|20(0[0-9]|1[0-7])** - Casa anos de 19__ até 2000 até 2017

**\d{2}-\d{2}\s** - Aqui são as partes subsequentes da data : mês e dia. *Não validado ainda pois aparentemente só o ano vem errado.* E incuindo qualquer espaço usando o **\s**

**(\d{2}:){2}\d{2})"** - Nessa parte seria a estrutura do horário, onde vem dois conjuntos de elementos compostos por 2 números seguidos por : e depois por último os 2 últimos números restantes.

Testei aqui com esses casos :

```
EMISSAO="2017-04-18 00:00:00" // passa
EMISSAO="1990-04-18 00:00:00" // passa
EMISSAO="2016-04-18 00:00:00" // passa
EMISSAO="2015-04-18 00:00:00" // passa
EMISSAO="2017-04-18 00:00:00" // passa
EMISSAO="2018-04-18 00:00:00" // não passa
EMISSAO="22000 00:00:00" // não passa
EMISSAO="2016-04-18 00:00:00" // passa
EMISSAO="65321-04-18 00:00:00" // não passa
EMISSAO="5069 00:00:00" //não passa
EMISSAO="2018 00:00:00" //não passa
EMISSAO="2019 00:00:00" //não passa
EMISSAO="2020 00:00:00" //não passa
```

Comment: teste `EMISSAO="2001-04-18 00:00:00"`

Comment: Com esse não funcionou?

Comment: Agora provavelmente está funcionando..

Answer (score 3):

Se um ano inválido começar apartir do 3000 pode usar a seguinte regex `[3-9]\d{3,}`. Ela casa um númer que comece entre 3 ou 9 seguindo de quais quer outros dígitos pelos menos três vezes.

```
"414-10-12 17:04:29" //não casa
"6014-10-12 17:04:29" //casa
"8014-10-12 17:04:29" //casa
"85014-10-12 17:04:29" //casa
"2019" //não casa
"3000" //casa
```

Comment: Ele quer os anos no futuro do ano atual , esses são inválidos.. 2018 é inválido mas não casa com sua regex

Answer (score 3):

Esta abaixo não é a maneira mais otimizada para a sua situação, pois existem algumas possibilidades a serem exploradas que você não levantou em sua pergunta, porem segue abaixo uma possível *Regex* para sua situação:

```
/(1[0-9]{3}|20(0[0-9]|1[0-7]))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\s+00:00:00/g
```

Answer (score 3):

Marcar com o prefixo "###" os anos estranhos, e depois editar para correção manual:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<=EMISSAO=")(\d{4,})/$1 < 2018 ? $1 : "###$1"/ge' ex.xml
sublime ex.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando a [resposta do @Marlysson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187470/14213).

E ajustando para logica que você necessita :

> O número 65321 representa o ano e é um ano que sequer existe (inválido), preciso ver onde os anos estão acima de 2017 para corrigir.

Ou seja você quer *matchs* inválidos e não validos.

Ajustando REGEX para ficar assim :

`^EMISSAO="(?(?!(19\d{2}|20(0\d|1[0-7]))-\d{2}-\d{2}).*|)$`

- Note que estou desconsiderando o que vem apos a data, no caso a parte em que o @Marlysson fez `\s(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}"` de verificar a sentença toda.

#### Logica

- A logica usada é de inversão, ou seja eu tenho que saber o *matchs* validos para então não capturá-los. Para isso usei o `(?!...)`
- Para realizar a ação de captura do que não é valido usei a logica de Ternário em REGEX `(?(?{option}`*REGEX*`)then|else)`.

#### Explicação

- `^EMISSAO="` - sentença literal, desde o inicio
- `(?!(19\d{2}|20(0\d|1[0-7]))-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Se bater com essa sentença é "false".
- `(?`**boolean**`.*|)` - Quando for verdadeira captura tudo, quando for false não captura nada.
- `$` - Fim da captura.

Seja no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/2UeOrg/3)

Answer (score 2):

Teste a seguinte expressão regular para saber se uma data é válida:

```
EMISSAO=\"([0-9]{4,}(?<=0*2(0(1[8-9]|[2-9][0-9])|[1-9][0-9]{2})|[3-9][0-9]{3}))-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]):(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])\"
```

`([0-9]{4,}(?<=0*2(0(1[8-9]|[2-9][0-9])|[1-9][0-9]{2})|[3-9][0-9]{3}))` =>  Qualquer ano que não esteja entre o ano 0 e 2017

`(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` => Qualquer mês de 1 até 12

`(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])` => Qualquer dia de até 31

`(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])` => Qualquer hora de 0 até 23

`(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])` => Qualquer minuto de 0 até 59

`(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])` => Qualquer segundo de 0 até 59

Answer (score 0):

> preciso ver onde os anos estão acima de 2017

#### Expressão regular

```
\b0*(?:(?:[12]\d|[3-9])\d{3,}|2(?:0(?:1[89]|[2-9]\d)|[1-9]\d{2}))(?=-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

Teste aqui: https://regex101.com/r/uejZaR/1

[image: Testes em regex101.com]